# Image is not showing if image URL is type "HTTPS"

Tags: android, image, https, picasso, android-glide

I am loading an image from "HTTP" URL and it's working well, but now that my image URL comes with "**HTTPS**" my image is not loading in imageview.

I tried picasso as well as glide but both failed to load the image with URL "HTTPS". If URL is with "HTTP" then there is no any issue, but it is not working with HTTPS.
So is there any final solution to load an image with HTTPS URL with only using picasso or glide?

I read so many article and tell us to use custom picasso class or use image loader library but no solutions.

Following are picasso example to load image:

```
  picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load("https://example_image_url.jpg")
                .fit()
                .noFade()
                .placeholder(image_here)
                .error(error_image_here)
                .into(my_image_view);
```

Comment: follow Jake Wharton answer from here. https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/500

Comment: i follow same link but not working

Comment: only solution for me is that i replace image url with https to http